". . . he is left having to feed Edward spaghetti and have his bottom pinched by Martin."
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 26)

Before the performance of the play, William (= he) reasoning


In spite of being able to remain fully clothed, on balance William still regrets being the only one to switch gender. As a male character, he most certainly would have had some opportunity to be amorous towards one of the twins, and perhaps even better, have one of them be amorous towards him. Instead he is left having to feed Edward spaghetti and have his bottom pinched by Martin.

I'm not sure who is doing what in the sentence in question. In my opinion William (=he) has to feed Edward spaghetti and Martin has to pinch William's bottom.

William must submit to the situation in which Martin pinches William's bottom.  It's a passive construction: William via the intermediary of his bottom is the passive recipient of the pinch.

William is "left" , i.e. the situation puts William in the position or role.  William is cast in the role in which William's bottom is pinched by Martin.

It looks like "the twins" are a couple of unspecified girls, not Edward and Martin. But you're reading the book, so I suppose you'll know that.

@FumbleFingers - Yes, you are right. The twins are Martin's young sisters

Consider this scenario: you've been working at a company for several years and your immediate supervisor trusts your work; you can send reports directly to the CEO without your supervisor needing to review them first.  But your supervisor leaves the company to work elsewhere, and you now have a newly hired person as your supervisor, and this new supervisor wants to review every report you write before it is  sent to the CEO.  You could say

When my supervisor resigned, I was left having to have my reports reviewed by a person new to the company.

having to have my reports reviewed is a continuous form that indicates that the new review requirement is something to which you must submit on an ongoing basis.  It is the continuous form of "have to have", which means "to be obliged to have" :

Children with recurrent tonsilitis have to have their tonsils taken out.

and so the continuous means "to be repeatedly obliged to have":

Because people are living longer, some are having to have their cataracts removed multiple times.


Thank you very much for this very informative answer :)
